# Custom Azure DevOps task has satisfies section but is not satisfying demands

Tags: maven, azure-devops, task, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am trying to run a build without having Maven already directly installed on an ADO self-hosted agent. I would like to be able to have a task do the Maven installation for me AND satisfy the demand requirement that some builds have. (The builds have a Maven demand but the agent doesnt have Maven installed until the task runs.)

In the Maven installer task I have a satisfies section that looks like:

```html
“satisfies”: [
“maven”
],
```

There are tasks in Microsoft repo that have the same tag as above, but for different softwares. Please see these repositories:

(This repo satisfies DotNetCore)
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/DotNetCoreInstallerV1/task.json

(This repo satisfies Java and JDK)
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/JavaToolInstallerV0/task.json

The Microsoft tasks with a satisfies section will satisfy demands, while mine does not.

I’m assuming that that the Satisfy section will Satisfy Demands that certain pipelines will have. Is this assumption correct? Or does anyone know what is the satisfies section is for??

Answer (score 0):

I think the demands section, not the satisfies section, defines the demands of the pipeline.

Here is the sample code from `tasks.schema.json` of demands and the description said that

> this section define a list of demands that a build agent requires to
> run this build task.

```
"demands": {
  "type": "array",
  "description": "Allows you to define a list of demands that a build agent requires to run this build task.",
  "items": {
    "type": "string"
  }
},
```

Comment: I think the demands section lists what demands the task requires of the agents.  However, I'm looking to satisfy a task that has a demand on an agent and will fulfill the demand simply by executing the task.   

`EX:
1) Task requires Maven to be on Agent.

2) Agent does not have Maven installed.

3) Task has satisfies section listing Maven, Task will also install Maven on the agent

4) ADO chooses Agent that does not have Maven and then Task installs Maven satisfying the demand.
`
Hopefully this makes sense!

Comment: Would also be interested in ignoring/satisfying a specific task demand of a predefined task